# Make textarea like CKEditor

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, ckeditor, textarea

How can I make simple textarea that will act like CKEditor? For example, pressing enter it will automatically go to the new line or pressing TAB it will make spaces and etc.? Because I added CKEditor to my project, but when I make it empty it does not give a validation error in codeigniter3. Actually, it gives errors, but before getting the error I also should make empty other fields, however when I delete CKEditor it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how can I fix the error. You need to paste this code at the top of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function()
{
    $.each( CKEDITOR.instances, function(instance) 
    {
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].on("change",function(e) 
        {               
            for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances)
            CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its too huge efforts to create textarea like CKEditor. If you have problem with `validation` because it by default add few `html tags`, in this case here is one trick. Which will help you to go forward with CKEditor.

By Default you need to load CKEditor in source mode like mentioned below.

```
function () {
    // set the startup mode
    CKEDITOR.config.startupMode = 'source';
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
}
```

This will help you. Let me know if it not works.

```js
// set the startup mode 
CKEDITOR.config.startupMode = 'source'; 
CKEDITOR.replace('insdescription1');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 input-group" > 
<textarea type="text" id="insdescription1" name="insdescription1" class=" form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Description"></textarea> 
</div> 

<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Comment: To be honest, I did not get what you mean. Where should I write this code?

Comment: Please check my updated answer, also it will gives you validation errors when empty

Comment: should I write it in script tag?

Comment: Yes, and replace this line `CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');` with your textarea ID

Comment: I made this, it did not work https://yadi.sk/i/OvZg-bgI3LYaKg

Comment: Can you please share your html

Comment: nice suggestion one up from my side.  @ShyamShingadiya

Comment: Here is how is the bug look like https://cloud.mail.ru/public/KqYu/7v5yJpXkb

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I think is that you can use [tinymce](https://www.tinymce.com/) for that. It will work very fine and also has a small footprint.  Here is the example.
Just Apply this code wherever you want to need the text editor.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea>Your text</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You think TinyMCE is better than CKEditor?

Comment: I have used `TinyMCE` many times and it's easy to implement, about `CKEditor` I don't know because I am not using that very much. you are free to use any one. But you should give a shot to `TinyMCE` once. @A.Aliyev

Comment: To try this u can directly copy the code and try at your side.

Comment: It also does not show errors when the textarea is empty :(

Comment: you can use jquery to validate or CodeIgniter has great validation rules. use that. @A.Aliyev

Comment: I am using CodeIgniter validations. It works when I use just simple textarea, but when I use editors it doesn't work

Comment: See this SO question to validate [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20933489/codeigniter-validation-not-happenning-because-of-tinymce-textarea)

Comment: Here is how is the bug look like https://cloud.mail.ru/public/KqYu/7v5yJpXkb